# How to give an alternative proof of the chain rule using the little-o notation?

Tags: proof-writing

**The chain rule.** If $g$ is a function that is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is a function that is differentiable at $g(x)$, then $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $x$, and $(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x).$

**Question:** I know the definition of the little-o notation. I also know that "$f$ is differentiable at $x$ $\iff$ there exists a real number $f'(x)$ such that $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$". But could someone show how to give an alternative proof of the chain rule using the little-o notation? (I think I am stuck at understanding the algebraic properties of the little-o notation.) Also, is it possible to give an alternative proof of the inverse function rule using the little-o notation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Straightforward. $f(g(x+h))=f(g(x)+hg'(x)+o(h))=f(g(x))+f'(g(x))(hg'(x)+o(h))+o(hg'(x)+o(h))= f(g(x))+f'(g(x))g'(x)h+o(h)$.

Comment: @A.S. Could you teach me why $(hg'(x)+o(h))$ becomes $g'(x)h$ and why $o(hg'(x)+o(h))$ becomes $o(h)$? I am stuck at understanding the algebraic properties of the little-o notation...

Comment: $o(ch)=o(h)$ for any constant $c$ and $g'(x)$ and such are just constants and $o(h)+o(h)=o(h)$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4734598/642262).